# If $f(x) = \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{2^{n(n-1)/2} n!}$ then $f^{-1}(f(x)-f(x-1))-\frac{x}{2}$ is bounded

Tags: asymptotics, inverse

For every $x>0$, let $$f(x) = \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{2^{n(n-1)/2} n!}.$$
Let $f^{-1}$ be the functional inverse of $f$.

How to show there exists a positive real constant $C$  such that, for all $x$,
$$\left(f^{-1}\left(f(x)-f(x-1)\right)-\frac{x}{2}\right)^2 < C $$

Edit :
I believe this is true because $f'(x) = f(x/2)$.

Comment: Any suggestions for improving the title ?

Comment: Why do you think this is true?

Comment: Because $f ′ (x)=f(x/2)$ . That is an analogue where the difference operator is replaced by a differential operator.
@martycohen

Comment: Do you mean "there exists a fixed positive real constant $C$ such that, for all $x$, ..."?

Comment: @Did thats what I said in reverse order right ?

Comment: Except that in the order you wrote it, there is nothing to prove...

Comment: Hmm I see , well I argue that the way I said it should be OK due to the word " fixed ". But because I want to be formal and clear I will edit.
So instead of arguing , I say thanks.
( the discussion belongs more on chat anyway )

Comment: "the discussion belongs more on chat anyway" No.

Comment: Thanks for the edit(s) @Did

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that $x\gt1$ then $f'(t)=f\left(\frac{t}2\right)$ for every $t\gt0$ and $f$ is increasing on the interval $\left(\frac{x-1}2,\frac{x}2\right)$ hence $$f(x)-f(x-1)=\int_{x-1}^xf'(t)\mathrm dt=\int_{x-1}^xf\left(\tfrac{t}2\right)\mathrm dt,$$ yields $$f\left(\tfrac{x-1}2\right)\leqslant f(x)-f(x-1)\leqslant f\left(\tfrac{x}2\right),$$ that is, $$\tfrac{x-1}2\leqslant f^{-1}\left(f(x)-f(x-1)\right)\leqslant\tfrac{x}2,$$ in particular, $$\left(f^{-1}\left(f(x)-f(x-1)\right)-\tfrac{x}2\right)^2\leqslant\tfrac14.$$

Comment: I think that as x grows to + infinity we get the limit :$\left(f^{-1}\left(f(x)-f(x-1)\right)-\frac{x}{2}\right)^2 = 0$

Comment: Im sorry , I wanted to give you the bounty but I had no time for MSE :(